# C++, overloading functions with array, as default

Tags: c++, arrays, overloading

Hey i was looking for some silly help i am starting with c++ in my studies, wanted my program for my professor to look better but.

I am stuck at overloading functions with array as default parameter..

```
 using namespace std;
int kol[8]={0};
void zad(int a){
zad(a,*b[]);
// this is bad overload don't know how
// need to couple to void zad(int a,int b[]=kol)..
}
void zad(int a,int b[]=kol){
 // do know is this correct code block didn't say anything
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by bad overload? There is no such concept! What you want to do with overloading?

Comment: wanted to use zad(1) without using zad(1,&array) at least  or use reference insude a function to that array..

Answer (score 0):

```
void zad(int a,int b[]=kol){
 // do know is this correct code block didn't say anything
}
```

is not valid syntax. You can only say `arg=literal` for default arg decalrarions. Do

```
void zad(int a,int b[]){
 // do know is this correct code block didn't say anything
}
void zad(int a){
   zad(a, zol);
}
```

ie create an overload with the full param list and call it with the args you want to pass;

Comment: Any reason to prefer this over `zad(int a, int b[] = {0})`?

Comment: because i dont know that he really needs a default value. In general I prefer not to use them

Comment: That *is* valid syntax. There is no restriction to literal default argument declarations. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95119e34c6bfe6e8

Comment: At least in this case ,`zad(int a, int b[] = {0})` have a disadvantage: it forces to duplicate the code defines `kol`. This could be a problem when you want to change the default value but forgot to change it in all places.

Comment: Wanted to use now zad(0); instead giving second parameter -delete the zad(int a ) declaration gives Lab4_1xx.cpp||undefined reference to `zad(int)'|

Comment: So none one has a clue how to run zad(a,x) by calling zad(a), where x is array...

Comment: @MrNIce um - i think my code showed you exactly that

Comment: post the exact code and the exact error message in your question